# Is there a valid way to force a white space between list items when HTML is minified?

Tags: html, css, minify, justify

I am trying to make use of `text-align: justify;` to space the list items out. ([LIKE THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/csjr0pg0/1/))

The problem is that my HTML is **minified** - which removes the spaces between the list items and ruins the `text-align: justify;` effect ([LIKE THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/csjr0pg0/2/))

So usually I get around this problem by adding an `&nbsp;` char between elements - ensuring that my whitespace is preserved.

Now although this actually works for list items too ([LIKE THIS - (the last demo there)](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/2p1u45pj/1/)) the problem here is that adding `&nbsp;` between list items is invalid HTML -

I tried the [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/) - and I got this error:

[image]

One more thing: I can't use `display:flex;` with `justify-content : space-between;` because I need to suppport IE9

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're using to minify. See if any solutions exist that allow you to preserve inter-element whitespace in certain places.

Comment: In whatever minifier you use, look for an "Keep empty text nodes" option (or anything similarly worded).

Comment: Who cares about html validator your webpage works what else do you want

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't use a `<table></table>` to create evenly spaced columns of content.

Comment: Look at the examples... tables don't do this layout

Comment: @myninjaname: I don't understand why anyone would. There is nothing about this that says it's a table. Unless you're suggesting using a table for layout, in which case, really?

Comment: @BoltClock When I see a single row spanning the entire width of its parent having multiple columns of evenly spaced content, I think table, not ul.

Comment: @BoltClock - you might be interested in the amazing solution here. It's a cross browser CSS only solution. Can you believe it?

Comment: Yeah, it's thanks to how inlines work fundamentally. I would still recommend finding a different minifier if you can, but otherwise CSS is fine if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a space after each list item as generated content, but then the list items need to be laid out as inline elements, not as inline blocks, in order to make the spaces matter in justification:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline;
}
.nav li:after {
    content: " "; /* a regular space */
}
.nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The last rule above handles the issue that a link may contain spaces and you probably do not want them to be stretched (as they would be if the element were inline).

**Original answer,** written before learning the difference between inline and inline block elements in justification; retained here for reference:

No, if you have “minified” HTML code so that whitespace between elements has been removed, you cannot make the elements act as “words” in justification. Such “minification” generally changes the actual content and should not be done—it is OK to collapse inter-element whitespace to one whitespace character, but not more.

The reason is that justification algorithms recognize only whitespace in actual content. Thus, it would not help to add spaces as generated content.

So you should use a more adequate minifier, or perhaps use the settings of the one you are using, so that it does not remove inter-element whitespace.

Comment: Thank you, I like the idea of collapsing  inter-element whitespace to one whitespace character. Cheers.

Comment: "...justification algorithms recognize only whitespace in actual content. Thus, it would not help to add spaces as generated content." [Surely not](http://jsfiddle.net/2p1u45pj/2/)

Comment: @Alohci, you’re right, things are different for `display: inline` than for `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Alohci and Jukka Thanks! that's amazing, I didn't think I could do this with generated content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - one caveat here is that if there are spaces within the text of any of the list items - then each word is spaced out like an individual list item. [LIKE THIS] (http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/csjr0pg0/4/) - so I might have to  stick to your first solution - ... or is there another way?

Comment: @Danield, good point. It seems that you can prevent that by setting `white-space: pre` on the `li` elements. Edited the answer again.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - thanks for that. I tried tried it and it works fine for webkit and FF but unfortunately it fails in IE. Sorry about being a help vampire here. :(

Comment: @Danield, oh, too bad. Looks like the original answer might be better after all...

Comment: @Danield - You can always use `display:inline-block` [on the `<a>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/csjr0pg0/6/). Just as long as the generated content space and `display:inline` is on the `<li>` element.

Comment: I think we have a winner... I’ll update the answer with @Alohci’s idea, which seems fix the issue.

Comment: @Alohci and JukkaK.Korpela - thanks. It's answers like these that make SO such a great place. I didn't really think there would be a CSS solution here. This may very well be the only place on the internet that this solution is covered.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to space the li elements with margin or padding

```
li {
   margin: 0 10px;
}
```